# How to add array values to an object

Tags: javascript

I have an array with few values. I want to iterate over array and add those values to an object as value starting from second object element which has `null` value. I cannot figure out how can I do it properly. Here is my code

```
let objectParameters = {
      "current_lang" : currentLang,
      "project_name" : null,
      "project_type" : null,
      "min_price"    : null,
      "max_price"    : null
}

let arrayValues = ["Project name", "Project Type", 150, 950];

arrayValues .forEach(function(item) {

 //Add array value to an object
}
```

Desired output

```
let objectParameters = {
      "current_lang" : currentLang,
      "project_name" : "Project name",
      "project_type" : "Project Type",
      "min_price"    : 150,
      "max_price"    : 950
}
```

Comment: Add how? In which way? What's the desired output?

Comment: Please show us the desired output for your example.

Comment: added, how the output should look like

Comment: this `["Project name", "Project Type", 150, 950]` array will be same always ?

Comment: no different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this :

```js
let objectParameters = {
      "current_lang" : "currentLang",
      "project_name" : null,
      "project_type" : null,
      "min_price"    : null,
      "max_price"    : null
};

let arrayValues = ["Project name", "Project Type", 150, 950],
  keys = Object.keys(objectParameters);
  
keys.shift() // Removing the first key, which is not null

keys.forEach( (key,i) => objectParameters[key] = arrayValues[i])

console.log(objectParameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the properties of an object with

`Object.keys(objectParameters)`

as an array and assign them values from your `arrayValues`

Like that:

```js
let objectParameters = {
      "current_lang" : "en",
      "project_name" : null,
      "project_type" : null,
      "min_price"    : null,
      "max_price"    : null
}

let arrayValues = ["Project name", "Project Type", 150, 950];


let params = Object.keys(objectParameters);

for(let i = 1; i < params.length; i++) {
  objectParameters[params[i]] = arrayValues[i-1];
}

console.log(objectParameters);
```

Comment: @Leo he also said "second object element"

Answer (score 1):

Using [for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the object and [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/shift) to get the first array element each iteration, in all cases we rely on the order, that is probably not a good approach.

```js
let objectParameters = {
    "current_lang" : "currentLang",
    "project_name" : null,
    "project_type" : null,
    "min_price"    : null,
    "max_price"    : null
}

let arrayValues = ["Project name", "Project Type", 150, 950];

for(let p in objectParameters){
    if(!objectParameters[p])
    objectParameters[p] = arrayValues.shift()
}

console.log(objectParameters)
```

I don't see necessary to use `hasOwnProperty` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the corresponding value in the array you dont need the loop and can just do:

```
objectParameters["project_name"] = arrayValues[0]
objectParameters["project_type"] = arrayValues[1]  
...
```

if you have the array values when youre creating the object you can just use them at the object creation time:

```
let objectParameters = {
      "current_lang" : "en",
      "project_name" : arrayValues[0],
      ...
}
```

Comment: how many params does your object have. If its the same for each, create a function passing in the object and the array and returning the object

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you got ordered array and object, here this code might help you:

```
        var obj = {
            'first': '1',
            'second': '2'
        };

        var arr = ['first', 'sec'];

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key, arrIndex) {
           obj[key] = arr[arrIndex];
        });
```

Then you edit  and optimize it the way you want. 
Little improvement, thank to @Jeremy Thille

Comment: You could just track `arrIndex` using `.forEach(function (key,arrIndex)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `arrayValues` format value will be same then you could use separate keys and use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for your arrays values and [`Destructuring_assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

**DEMO**

```js
const keys = ["project_name", "project_type", "min_price", "max_price"],
  arrayValues = ["Project name", "Project Type", 150, 950];

let result = arrayValues.reduce((r, v, i) => {
  return { ...r,
    [keys[i]]: v
  }
}, {current_lang:navigator.language});


console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```